# GetUserInfo function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I have an assignment where I have to print a users age and name based on their input.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void GetUserInfo(int* userAge, char userName[]) {
   printf("Enter your age: \n");
   scanf("%d", userAge);
   printf("Enter your name: \n");
   scanf("%s", userName);
   return;
}

int main(void) {
   int userAge = 0;
   char userName[30] = "";
   //insert code here
   printf("%s is %d years old.\n", userName, userAge);
   return 0;
}
```

I can't change any code except for the //insert code here.
I'm pretty sure that I have to call the function but I can't figure out what parameters to pass the function. I tried

```
void GetUserInfo(int* userAge, char userName[]);
```

but as you can probably figure out it passes an empty string for a name and 0 as the age due to the initializations in the `main()`.

Comment: It seems that you're very new to programming. Your attempted answer is known as a function declaration. What you're looking for is a function call that takes parameters by reference. I'm not going to give you the answer, as you will not learn anything. Instead, study this post, and try and figure this out on your own. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you need for the function are a pointer to int and a pointer to char.

GetUserInfo(&userAge, userName);

The "&" operator gives you the address of the userAge variable that can be used as a pointer.

The compiler will take care of passing the start of the userName array of chars as second parameter.